# Multiprocessing process instability problem in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm dealing with a high-dimensional matrix operation on a large amount of data, and I've divided it into 20 processes, I ran it  in my lab with Linux system, but I found that not every loop starts 20 processes.
Because I printed the time and found that the difference between each loop was very large (which should be close), I didn't know why?

Here is my relevant code, it is some functions which is in a class.

```
import numpy as np
import time

from scipy import sparse
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

    def _computeTR(self, num_batch, data, W):
        n = data.shape[0]
        poolSize = self.poolSize  # 20
        batch = n // poolSize
        assert n % poolSize == 0
        compute_W = W[num_batch * batch:(num_batch + 1) * batch]
        compute_data = data[num_batch * batch:(num_batch + 1) * batch, ...]

        T = 0
        R = 0
        for i in range(batch):
            B = compute_W[i]
            x = compute_data[i]
            s0 = B.T.dot(x)
            s0 = s0.reshape(self.D * self.Ks, 1)
            s0 = sparse.csc_matrix(s0)
            T += (self.eta - 1) * s0 @ s0.T + B.T @ B
            R += self.eta * s0
        return T, R

    def multiprocessing_computeTR(self, data, W):
        p = Pool(self.poolSize)
        a = p.map_async(partial(self._computeTR,data=data,W=W), range(self.poolSize)).get()
        p.close()
        p.join()
        T = 0
        R = 0
        for i in range(self.poolSize):
            T += a[i][0]
            R += a[i][1]
        return T, R
```

```
while iter_num < maxiter
    iter_num += 1
    time1 = time.time()
    Ts, Rs = self.multiprocessing_computeTR(data,self.W)
    time2 = time.time()
    print(time2 - time1)
```

The output:

49.9

885.9

719.7

587.7

259.9

This was unexpected.

Comment: Does having .get() on the same line as the push to map_async make any difference? Not sure on the co-existence of .get() and .join() either. Also - had a sort of kinda of a little bit maybe similar problem before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902519/multiprocessing-not-spawning-all-the-requested-processes/66982614#66982614  I run my multiprocessing slightly differently to yourself - might be worth a try if you don't get any other responses.